# cURL returns same result for different pages

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to download the list data from goodreads with curl in php but it always returns the same result for different pages. I mean, the result of `?page=1` and `?page=2` is the same. How can i solve this problem? Sorry for my bad english, thanks.

```
$data1 = getGoodreadsList("http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/43005.En_yi_T_rk_e_eviriler?page=");
var_dump($data1);

public function getGoodreadsList($link){
    $result = [];

    for($page=1;$page<29;$page++){
        $html = str_get_html($this->downloadUrl($link . strval($page)));

        foreach($html->find(".bookTitle") as $book){
            array_push($result, "http://www.goodreads.com" . $book->href);
        }

        $html->clear(); 
        unset($html);

        if($page == 2){
            break;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

private function downloadUrl($url){
    $headers[]  = "User-Agent:'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36'";
    $headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
    $headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
    $headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it works on my end - it fetches a different page. I don't have a function `str_get_html` so I can't see beyond that, but what is returned by the cURL call itself is a correct page (if I compare it by opening it in browser)

Comment: It's common to iterate the .next_page links to get the full data. Take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/monkeysuffrage/72516fd80405294ed245916fc08d4250) to see what I mean.